# Add filename to dataframe csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to read multiple csv files in a directory, combine them to one dataframe, and add a column filename to the dataframe for each line item read.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'\OUTPUT'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='|') for f in all_files)
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
concatenated_df['filename'] =(all_files[f] for f in all_files)
```

My output looks like this:
[image]

instead of the filename, I get `<generator object>` in my last column. Could some tell me what am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Got it working?

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

The problem is each csv file has 1 name but multiple rows. So when you conactenate There are more rows in dataframe than there are files names.

`(all_files[f] for f in all_files)` is a generator that means it will generate files when called upon. And you are broadcasting the generator `__str__()` method return value to the DataFrame's column. Although this is useless as `all_files` already has all the names in a list.

## Solution

So just do:

```
# your code upto last second line
all_file_names = []
for f in all_files:
  # read the dataframe and add the row times the file name to the all_file_names
  all_file_names += [f]*pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='|').shape[0]

concatenated_df['filename'] = all_files_names
```

Make sure the length of `all_file_names` and the `concatenated_df` rows are equal length.

Comment: That wont really work, the list all_files is not the same length as the dataset. Multiple line items can  belong to the same file. When I try the above, I get the below error: 
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: That means you are on the right track. The problem is **each csv file has 1 name but multiple rows**. So when you conactenate There are more rows in dataframe than there are files names. Got it?

Comment: Sol 1: Broadcast the file name to only those rows which belongs to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the rows from a file need to have that file's name in your `concatendated_df`, you can first count the no. of rows you have from each file, and save the filename that many times in a list. And then just assign that list's values to your **filename** column.

Below code should work for you:

```
df_from_each_file = [pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='|') for f in all_files]
no_of_rows_in_each_df = [df.shape[0] for df in df_from_each_file]
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
concatenated_df['filename'] =  [f for f, i in zip(all_files, no_of_rows_in_each_df) for _ in range(i)]
```

Comment: @hbm0102  let me know if this solved your issue, or if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you can use. First create your `DataFrames` and store them in a `dict` where the dictionary keys are your file paths. This makes it easy to assign file paths to a column before concatenating.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# This returns a list of file paths
all_csv_file_paths = glob.glob('*.csv')

# We create a dictionary using list of filepaths as the dict keys
df_dictionary = {filepath: pd.read_csv(filepath) for filepath in all_csv_file_paths}

# Now we can iterate of our dictionary items
# The dictionary items are our DataFrames
# We can create a new filepath column and populate is with each
# DataFrame's filepath
for each_filepath, each_df in df_dictionary.items():
    each_df['filepath'] = each_filepath

# Finally we concatenate all of our DataFrames by passing the 
# dictionary values (which are our DataFrames) to pd.concat()
pd.concat(df_dictionary.values(), ignore_index=True)
```